# Argument type 'String?' does not conform to expected type 'StringProtocol'

Tags: ios, swift, string, string-comparison, swift5

[image]

This error occurs when using `compare` on a `String` in `Swift 5`, it accepts only `StringProtocol`, but I want to use it on `String` and can't find nowhere how to do it.

I've searched all over and can't understand what seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem that `Optional<String>` (aka `String?`) is not conform to `StringProtocol` (and that makes sense). You should unwrap optional, there is several ways:

1. Unwrapping by `if let`/`guard`
   (`if let version = dbData?.version {
   //compare 
   }`)
2. Providing default value ( `(dbData?.version ?? "")), which is not recommended, because it can provide unnecessary collisions
3. Force unwrap  `dbData!.version`, which is highly not recommended, because it can involve crashing an app, if Optional was `nil`

Comment: Using Optional's map function is another way that can be helpful. Something like `dbData?.version.map { version.compare($0, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) }` with this way you can only do the comparison if the value is not nil and you can provide a default value that might make more sense at the end of it with `??`.

Comment: @Helam perfect suggestion, but I feel it a little not natural way although I love functional approach. Still upvote, buddy!

Comment: Perfect answer. But I don't understand why Apple don't write a normal help about the warning so people could understand?